# Is it possible to have dynamic authorized redirect URI for Google cloud's OAuth 2.0?

Tags: javascript, docker, go, docker-compose, oauth-2.0

Please help me rephrase the question if it doesn't fully reflect what I want.

I have an app that consists of:

1)Go server API

2)Go server Frontend that utilizes API's endpoints

3)Docker container that runs both servers

During development I had localhost set statically in multiple places, such as:
1)In the API server for enabling CORS in order for Frontend to be able to communicate with the API
Example:

```
func enableCors(w *http.ResponseWriter) {
   (*w).Header().Set("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "http://localhost:8080")
   (*w).Header().Set("Access-Control-Allow-Credentials", "true")
}
```

2)In the API server for redirecting to and from the API in order to authenticate the user

3)In the Frontend server JavaScript part to access the API

4)In Google API Authorized redirect URIs as:

```
http://localhost:8001/oauth/authenticate?method=google
```

For the first time I want to make my application operate in a more production like way.
If every time someones downloads my application and builds a docker image from it the resulting container would have a different external IP address how should I set up my code structure to look like in order to account for this dynamic IP?(Especially with Google cloud APIs redirect for OAUTH)? Or am I fundamentally wrong and this is not possible/not wanted behavior in the first place as there usually is one server on which X application is hosted and its IP is always known and static in the real world?

The only thing I came up with if after all it is something achievable is to somehow get container IP inside the Dockerfile and then set it to an Environment variable that would then be used by both servers but that still doesn't solve the Google API OAUTH static allowed redirect URI problem. Hopefully, I was able to convey what the problem is because I have had trouble phrasing it.

Progress:
So far I have managed to set environment variable through a shell script during docker build like so:

```
export SERVER_IP=$(hostname -I | xargs)
```

and for the JavaScript I used webpack plugin Dotenv with systemvars parameter set to true to capture system env and incorporate it into JS.

Answer (score 0):

It is enough to ask users of your app to complete config file. They must write their own APIKey at least, and I think they will configure their Google API and can easily get their IP(or just writes their static domain name). You must only inform users in README.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).